# SharePoint 2013 - Disable Client Integration issue

Tags: office-integration

We have a zone where we would like to disable Client Integration for preventing Sharepoint to open the documents in Office. Instead we would like to have a download promt for the user when clicking on a document.

I have disabled Client Integration for the web app zone and it seems to work fine except for the column "Filename (linked to document with edit menu)". When clicking this one it tries to open the document in the application even though Client Integration is disabled.

The column "Filename (linked to document)" works fine and reacts to my changes in the Client Integration setting.

Can someone else recreate this problem and do you have any clue why the fields behave different?

..................................

Hmm, I just found that "Filename (linked to document with edit menu)" was surrounded by a div with an app attribute in it. By removing that attribute the behaviour was the expected. Now I guess that I have to write some JQuery to find those app attributes and remove them if I'm the zone where I would like to disable Client Integration. Do you think that removing that attribute can have some other consequences?

Comment: If "Filename (linked to document)" works as expected then you could save yourself the time and frustration of writing that JQuery script by using (Linked to document) instead of (linked to document with edit menu) and adding an "Edit" column to your view.